# Which is better: O(nm) or O(n log n)?

Tags: time-complexity

I came across a problem where O(nm) is being ran against O(n log n) and they say that one is better but it's not so obvious to me.

O(n log n) is better than O (n^2), but what about compared to O(n*m) with m being a non-constant?

Comment: Depends on whether m is bigger or smaller than log(n)...

Comment: "O(n log n) is better than O (n²)" is not absolutely true. In practice, the "hidden constants" matter.

Answer (score 2):

When you examine complexity, you must define your input.
When your input is `N`  and you want to compute a program complexity, given `N`, the result will be a function with `N` as an argument.
It is easy to compare between two different functions with the same input.

However, in your case, you are comparing a function that takes one argument (`N`) with a function that takes two arguments (`N and M`), while `M` is unknown **relatively** to `N`. Therefore, you can't really compare between them and get the answer you want.

For example, if `M` is defined as `M=N*C` (when C is a constant), you can say that `O(N*M)=O(N^2)>O(N*logN)`. But if M is defined as `M=log(log(N))*C`, then `O(N*M)=O(N*log(log(N)))<O(NlogN)`.

The key point here is that time complexity calculation always relays on **every** input, which they must be well defined relatively to the other arguments being compared.

So, the answer to `(N*M) ? O(N*logN)` depends on the relation between `M` and `N` (to be more specific: depends on if `M*C<log(N)*K`, when C and K are constants)

Comment: OTOH, usually `logN` is very small, and big-O talks about growth, so one normally assumes arbitrary inputs are vaguely large. I generally agree with what you wrote though

Comment: Indeed `logN` considered as very small and maybe the common non-constant function with big-O smaller than linear effective function that is being used in programs, but there are infinite functions that the big-O of them are between constant and logN, so there always be, theoretically speaking, a place for comparison. There are even some common time complexities that suitable to those situation, my example is one of them (the log-logarithmic)

Answer (score 0):

You can't answer for at least three reasons:

- if N and M are independent, there is no relation between log N and M;
- asymptotic complexities depend on the constants in the big-O notation, and even for two O(N) functions you don't know which is "better";
- big-O's are just upper bounds and if they are not tight, the true function can be quite different.